# how to extract text html using R

Tags: r

I need to extract the following a block of text from a set of google results obtained using

```
require(XML)
    require(RCurl)
input<-"R%statistical%Software"
 require(XML)
    require(RCurl)
    url <- paste("https://www.google.com/search?q=\"",
                 input, "\"", sep = "")

    CAINFO = paste(system.file(package="RCurl"), "/CurlSSL/ca-bundle.crt", sep = "")
    script <- getURL(url, followlocation = TRUE, cainfo = CAINFO)
    doc <- htmlParse(script)
```

in the R package XML

An extract of the extracted HTML document as follows

```
</ul></div>
</div>
</div>
<span class="st">R, also called GNU S, is a strongly functional language and environment to <br>
statistically explore data sets, make many graphical displays of data from custom<br>
Â <b>...</b></span><br>
</div>
<table class="slk" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin-top:1px">
<tr class="mslg">
<td style="padding-left:23px;vertical-align:top"><div class="sld">
```

In this example I need to extract the following text for each result returned

"R, also called GNU S, is a strongly functional language and environment to 
    statistically explore data sets, make many graphical displays of data from custom
"

I have had a go with some of the functions in the XML package for R, but I don't think I understand enough about HTML and XML. 
The text will vary for each result returned, so its actually the

```
<span class="st">
```

?field? I need to extract.
As you have probably guessed I am not familiar with HTML or XML. So any recommendations for a good tutorial or book that would give me enough of an overview to solve these kind of problems would be most welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post a link to the file you are parsing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This returns a list, `result` with the text from all span tags using `class="st"` (there are 7 in your document).

```
input<-"R%statistical%Software"
url <- paste0("http://www.google.com/search?q=",input)
doc <- htmlParse(url)
result <- lapply(doc['//span[@class="st"]'],xmlValue)
result[1]
# [[1]]
# [1] "R, also called GNU S, is a strongly functional language and environment to \nstatistically explore data sets, make many graphical displays of data from custom\n ..."
```

Note the use of http instead of https greatly simplifies retrieval of the document.