# Remove HTML tags from a text string and keep the text

Tags: r

I have a text string like the one below :-

```
^style>           
  p,span,li{font-family:Arial;font-size:10.5pt;}        
^/style>  
^p>
  ^img src="https://app.keysurvey.com/" alt="image" width="462" />
^/p>  
^p>
  Dear Adam,
^/p>  
^p>
  Thank you for your query, the Reference ID for your query is 
  ^strong>^u> 28600 ^/u>^/strong>
  .&nbsp; We will respond to you within the next 1-2 business days.
^/p>  
^p>For further correspondence with us, kindly reply by maintaining the 
   Reference ID number of this case in the subject line of your e-mail.
^/p>  
^p>
  Regards
^/p>
```

My Goal is to clear all html tags and other junk values and return a text like this:

Output :-

> Dear Adam,
>
> Thank you for your query, the Reference ID for your query is  We will
>   respond to you within the next 1-2 business days.For further
>   correspondence with us, kindly reply by maintaining the Reference ID
>   number of this case in the subject line of your e-mail.Regards,

I have tried `tm.plugin.webmining`, `extractHTMLStrip` however it could not clear the junk values

```
library(tm.plugin.webmining)
df$text1 <- extractHTMLStrip(df$text)
```

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times. Multiple solutions are available through various libraries or via regex. Try e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794897/how-to-extract-text-html-using-r) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54229207/remove-html-tags-from-a-text-string-and-keep-the-text)

Comment: these doesn't help anyways thank you second link is link to my question I have tried xml, Rcurl and RVest libraries to clear junk values however these doesnt help thanks and have good day

Comment: you can try `gsub("[^p]", "", x)` and then repeat that for anything you want to remove. This will replace any instances of `^p` with nothing

Comment: Sorry, must have messed up copy and paste of the links. I provided an answer using regular expressions below, but if it is a case of corrupted strings, you can do `gsub("\\^", "<", df$text)`, which should make your hmtl tools work.

Answer (score 0):

If your string has less-than signs corrupted, you can do it with regular expressions.

```
yourstring <- '^style> p,span,li{ font-family:Arial; font-size:10.5pt; } ^/style> ^p>^img src="https://app.keysurvey.com/" alt="image" width="462" />^/p> ^p>Dear Adam,^/p> ^p>Thank you for your query, the Reference ID for your query is ^strong>^u> 28600 ^/u>^/strong>.  We will respond to you within the next 1-2 business days.^/p> ^p>For further correspondence with us, kindly reply by maintaining the Reference ID number of this case in the subject line of your e-mail.^/p> ^p>Regards'
# reproducible example of your string

yourstring <- gsub("\\^.*?>", "", yourstring)
yourstring <- gsub("p,span.*?}", "", yourstring)
yourstring <- trimws(yourstring)
```

this gets you:

```
> yourstring
[1] "Dear Adam, Thank you for your query, the Reference ID for your query is  28600 .  We will respond to you within the next 1-2 business days. For further correspondence with us, kindly reply by maintaining the Reference ID number of this case in the subject line of your e-mail. Regards"
```

To make it more elegant, you can use `stringr` and `magrittr` library.